# Как выровнять блок по вертикали?

Tags: html, css

Блок `.upd-text` нужно выровнять по вертикали:

```css
.upd-img{
    float:left;
    width:58px;
    height:58px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    margin: 0 7px 0 0;
}

.upd-text{
    width:230px;
    background-color:#cccccc;
    float:left;
    font: 10px helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="update-block">
    <div class="upd-img"></div>
    
    <div class="upd-text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Сначала напишите, какие браузеры поддерживаете. Это очень важно! Посмотрите вот здесь [Вертикальное выравнивание по центру](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/pozitsionirovanie/vertikalnoe-vyravnivanie-otnositelno-roditelya.html) - 1 cпособ годится для IE8+.

Comment: меня бы утроило узнать все способы, лишним никогда не будет)

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Решение через Flexbox

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  
  display: flex;
  /* Центрируем по вертикали */
  align-items: center;
  /* Центрируем по горизонтали */
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### 2. Решение через псевдоэлемент с поддержкой IE 9

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Обертка */
.container-fluid:before {
   content: '';
   height: 100%;
   display: inline-block !important;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Блок, который нужно выровнять */
.row {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### 3. Решение через абсолютное позиционирование

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.row{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

#### 4. Решение через line-height

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.row{
  line-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Так можно с line-height

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.row{
  line-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```